# Having trouble getting elements to change in HTML

Tags: html, css

I've already run my code through a validator, so there are no syntax errors, but I can't figure out what's going on. Nothing I do changes the "p" elements in my code. I've tried styling the p class. I've tried wrapping them in a "div" tag and stylizing that, but it just seems to keep inheriting the body properties. If I want to style the text at all, I have to do it through the body properties.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div id="topBar"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Escaping Shapes"/></div>
<div id="rope"><img src="images/rope2.png" alt="Bottom of logo border"/></div>
  <p>Yarrrrgh! Shapes be escaping from below the surface of the Web! Push'em back down below the page as fast as ye can!</p>

  <p class="bold">Your time: <span id="time">(not attempted yet)</span></p>


<div id="box">

</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the body:

```
body {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Here's the CSS for the "p" element that does NOTHING for me lol.

```
  p {
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;

    }
```

Not sure what's going on, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more of my code if necessary.

**EDIT** My Entire CSS:

```
    body {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #topBar {
        background-color: #2980b9;
        height: 120px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

        #topBar img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 600px;
            position: relative;
            top: 25px;
            left: -85px;
        }




    #box {
        background-color: #0ff;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #7e7e7e;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.1s linear;
        -moz-transition:all 0.1s linear ;
        -ms-width:all 0.1s linear ;
        -o-width:all 0.1s

    }

    #box:active {
        box-shadow: none;
        top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
       -webkit-transform:scale(0.25, 0.25);
       -moz-transform:scale(0.25, 0.25) ;
       -ms-width:scale(0.25, 0.25) ;
       -o-width:scale(0.25, 0.25) ;
    }

    #box:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    #rope {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-image: url(images/rope2.png);
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: -25px;


    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }



     p {
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;

    }
```

Comment: So, what's not working?

Comment: can you post your entire css?

Comment: there is no problem in you css. The <p> is working good enough in given code

Comment: Most of these properties overlap each other. Try changing some colors and see if it is working...

Comment: Rasel is correct.  Your code is fine and your css works fine.  If it's not working for you then there's something more to your html or css that we can't see that's causing your issue.  Here's a fiddle showing it working in action. http://jsfiddle.net/nw6qm4pa/

Comment: Here's my entire CSS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not closed off `-o-width:all 0.1s`
with a semi-colon under your #box css properties  This is your problem.

You also haven't closed off your #rope properties }

Comment: I tried that. That was super observant, but unfortunately it didn't help. On a side note, I feel like the validator should have picked up on that.

Comment: It's usually very simple things like this that cause css issues :) Here's the fiddle for my updated answer http://jsfiddle.net/nw6qm4pa/2/

Comment: I explained it above in my edited answer.  first I closed off -o-width:all 0.1s with a semi-colon ; Then I closed the end of your #rope css with a bracket }.  Forgetting little things like this will make any css that follows it not work.  Just be super diligent about checking these types of errors.

Comment: No worries that's what the community is here for. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your css.
The `<p>` is working good enough in your given code.
CSS properties overlap each other.So be careful about this.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pckg2kt/)

**edit:**
as your new edit
you are missing closing }
write

```
    #rope {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-image: url(images/rope2.png);
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: -25px;
}
```

instead of

## rope {

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-image: url(images/rope2.png);
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: -25px;
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/7pckg2kt/1/)

Comment: Already covered that along with the missing semi-colon on his #box properties.......about 8 minutes ago

Comment: yes i know. sorry for that.I answered it first and missing some time when this question edited again.Then i find the problem and answered it editing it.What should i do? Delete my previous answer which i answered before question edit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the p styles are being applied to the p.  I tried by setting the font color via the p rule and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/L2q1Lbzj/

```
body {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

 p {
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: red;

    }
```

Comment: Now everyone's being redundant.  This is not a solution it's a comment.  This is why more CSS is needed.